# ViewPager Functioning the first two page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

ViewPagerAdapter, I do not understand the behavior of the ViewPagerAdapter, I understand that it creates a forward position from which it is selected, for example if I select the position 0 at the beginning it returns me (0,1) and I select the 1 me returns (2), then To reach the last position already returns nothing because in theory the penuiltima and charge the utlima position, if I am in position 1 and wants to return no longer the load because I imagine it is already loaded, and if I move from position 0 to The last position return load (4, and three) is there any way to cancel this behavior or to load only the position in which you are without going a forward position

```
public class MainActivity extends Fragment {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("CONSOLE", "Main :::::::::: onCreateView");

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tablayout_menu);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager_menu);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 4"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 5"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        CostumerFragment2 adapter = new CostumerFragment2(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return rootView;
    }

    public class CostumerFragment2 extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public CostumerFragment2(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {
            System.out.println("POSICION: " + index);

            switch (index) {
                case 0:

                    return new Fragment1();

                case 1:

                    return new Fragment2();
                case 2:

                    return new Fragment3();
                case 3:

                    return new Fragment4();
                case 4:

                    return new Fragment5();


            }
            return null;


        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("CONSOLE", "Main :::::::::: onResume");


    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Log.d("CONSOLE", "Main :::::::::: onPause");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("CONSOLE", "Main :::::::::: onStart");

    }
}
```

*** NEW **

`

```
public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FrameLayout frameLayoutFragment;
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private AHBottomNavigation ahBottomNavigation;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("CONSOLE", "PAPA onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.principal);

        frameLayoutFragment = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.myFragemnt);
        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation);
        ahBottomNavigation = (AHBottomNavigation) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

        final AHBottomNavigationItem item1 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Menú", R.drawable.menu);
        AHBottomNavigationItem item2 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Favoritos", R.drawable.favoritos_item);
        AHBottomNavigationItem item3 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Tu orden", R.drawable.item_charola);
        AHBottomNavigationItem item4 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Perfil", R.drawable.item_perfil);

        ahBottomNavigation.addItem(item1);
        ahBottomNavigation.addItem(item2);
        ahBottomNavigation.addItem(item3);
        ahBottomNavigation.addItem(item4);
        ahBottomNavigation.setBehaviorTranslationEnabled(false);
        ahBottomNavigation.setAccentColor(R.color.colorAccent);
        ahBottomNavigation.setInactiveColor(R.color.colorPrimary);

        ahBottomNavigation.setForceTint(true);
        ahBottomNavigation.setTranslucentNavigationEnabled(true);

        ahBottomNavigation.setTitleState(AHBottomNavigation.TitleState.ALWAYS_SHOW);
        ahBottomNavigation.setTitleState(AHBottomNavigation.TitleState.ALWAYS_SHOW);

        ahBottomNavigation.setColored(false);

        ahBottomNavigation.setCurrentItem(1);

        ahBottomNavigation.setNotification("10", 1);
        ahBottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener(new AHBottomNavigation.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTabSelected(int position, boolean wasSelected) {
                // Do something cool here...
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        //item1.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

                        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myFragemnt, mainActivity);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();

                        return true;
                    case 1:

                        FragmentManager fm2 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = fm2.beginTransaction();

                        FragmentFavoritos fragmentFavoritos = new FragmentFavoritos();
                        fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.myFragemnt, fragmentFavoritos);
                        fragmentTransaction2.commit();

                        return true;
                    case 2:
                        FragmentManager fm3 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction3 = fm3.beginTransaction();

                        FragmentOrden fragmentOrden = new FragmentOrden();
                        fragmentTransaction3.replace(R.id.myFragemnt, fragmentOrden);
                        fragmentTransaction3.commit();

                        return true;
                    case 3:

                        FragmentManager fm4 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction4 = fm4.beginTransaction();

                        FragmentPerfil fragmentPerfil = new FragmentPerfil();
                        fragmentTransaction4.replace(R.id.myFragemnt, fragmentPerfil);
                        fragmentTransaction4.commit();


                        return true;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("CONSOLE", "PAPA onResume");


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("CONSOLE", "PAPA onPause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("CONSOLE", "PAPA onStart");

    }
}
```

`

Comment: This is an example, the Fragments are actually dynamic, but I want to know if I can get the position that you select and not the position of the next Fragment viewPager.getCurrentItem (), but as I send it to the fragment and it loads it so the GetItem You do not have a listener if you go back to the actual position.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** To get the current `selected` page `position`:

```
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // Here position is the selected page-position 
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

**2.** Go to specific `page`:

```
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(POSITION);
```

**3.** Change `page` as per `Tab` selection:

```
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            // Change page
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

**UPDATE:**

**#.** In your `onCreateView()` method:

```
CostumerFragment2 adapter = new CostumerFragment2(getChildFragmentManager());
```

Instead of:

```
CostumerFragment2 adapter = new CostumerFragment2(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
```

**#.** In `CostumerFragment2` add below method:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: With this I cancel the use of the FragmentPageAdapter? No longer need to use it and instead used these two methods the Tab and ViewPager? @FerdeousAhamed

Comment: tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager) does all the things but if you still need operation based on current selected page position then you can use these listener overrided methods

Comment: But it is not showing the content of the fragment, inside the fragment I have a text and shows only blank ViewPager

Comment: `tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener (nueva TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener () {void pestaña onTabSelected (TabLayout.Tab pública @ Override) {viewPager.setCurrentItem (tab.getPosition ()); System.out.println ( "POSICION:" + tab.getPosition () ); inflateFragmenSelectec (tab.getPosition ());}`

Comment: `public Fragment inflateFragmenSelectec(int position){
        switch (position){
            case 0: return  new Fragment1();
            case 1: return  new Fragment2();
            case 2: return  new Fragment3();
            case 3: return  new Fragment4();
            case 4: return  new Fragment5();
        }
        return  null;
    }`

Comment: i need the position to be inflated a fragment, but if i return the correct position but does not show the content of the fragments

Comment: what about @Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

    return POSITION_NONE;
}

Comment: where is your MainActivity exyending Activity to AppCompatActivity??

Comment: In reliadad is a fragment that inflate another fragment and my Activity contains an AHBottomNavigation, only in the first section there are tabs, just update my question by adding my Activity.

Comment: The behavior of the adapter is correct, but my question mentioned above on how can I override the behavior of the FragmentStatePagerAdapter from going a position ahead of selected, `@Override
Public Fragment getItem (int index) {`forward position, (load the next pager) at start load 2 pager, the current position and one right, after loading just the right one how can I avoid that?